# Reverse string in Common Lisp

Tags: string, common-lisp

**How can i reverse a string in Common Lisp?**

I want to transform "Hello World" into "dlroW olleH". In Python it is done using [extended slice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/931092/596361): `"Hello World"[::-1]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[reverse](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_revers.htm) can take any sequence, including strings, so you only have to write:

```
> (reverse "Hello World")
"dlroW olleH"
```